# Javascript boolean parameter not passing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

I created a function with various if statements,that will be executed if a parameter is true. But passing false as a parameter doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

```js
function easySlider(titleP, subTitleP, overlayP) {
  var title = titleP;
  var subTitle = subTitleP;
  var overlay = overlayP;

  if (title === true) {
    $(".sliderTitle").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".sliderTitle").css("display", "none");
  }

  if (subTitle === true) {
    $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display", "none");
  }

  if (overlay === true) {
    $(".sliderOverlay").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $(".sliderOverlay").css("display", "none");
  }
}

easySlider(true, false, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="sliderTitle">Hello sliderTitle</h2>
<h3 class="sliderSubTitle">Hello sliderSubtTitle</h3>
<div class="sliderOverlay">Hello sliderOverlay</div>
```

Comment: Other than not caching the DOM access and the unneeded assignments, there's nothing wrong with that code I can see. Also curious why you're not using `.hide` and `.show`...

Comment: Have you tried with a double equal (==) in the if statement?

Comment: _But passing false as a parameter doesn't seem to work_ What doesn't work? Describe the problem please

Comment: Are your IF statements resolving correctly?

Comment: What you have should work fine (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/ag0myjes/), although note you can shorten your code massively by just using `toggle()`: https://jsfiddle.net/ag0myjes/1/

Comment: @ope95 that is a *terrible* idea. Why would you even suggest that, *especially* in a boolean context...

Comment: Simplified JSFiddle of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/qpmt4wzq/  - It seems to be working fine...?

Comment: Have you included jQuery?  That's the only thing that would break the above code (assuming correct class names, of course).

Comment: does it work with true.

Comment: I've submitted an edit which converts your code into a snippet which will show that your code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div class="sliderTitle"></div>
<div class="sliderSubTitle"></div>
<div class="sliderOverlay"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function easySlider(title, subTitle , overlay) {
        var titleDisplay     = title ? 'block' : 'none';
        var subTitleDisplay  = subTitle ? 'block' : 'none';
        var overlayDisplay   = overlay ? 'block' : 'none';

        $(".sliderTitle").css("display", titleDisplay);
        $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display", subTitleDisplay);
        $(".sliderOverlay").css("display", overlayDisplay);
    }

    easySlider(false, false, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <p class="sliderTitle">
    Slider Title
    </p>
    <p class="sliderSubTitle">
    Slider Subtitle
    </p>
    <p class="sliderOverlay">
    Slider Overlay
    </p>

<script>
function easySlider(titleP,subTitleP,overlayP){

    var title = titleP;
    var subTitle = subTitleP;
    var overlay = overlayP;

    if(title===true) {
     $(".sliderTitle").css("display","block");
    }else{
     $(".sliderTitle").css("display","none");
    }
    if(subTitle===true) {
     $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display","block");
    }else{
     $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display","none");
    }
    if(overlay===true) {
     $(".sliderOverlay").css("display","block");
    }else{
     $(".sliderOverlay").css("display","none");
    }
}   


easySlider(true,false,false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/me2b0r56/

seems to be working fine...

Comment: That's because jsfiddle by default wait the document ready state before running javascript. Just edit settings to make it run immediately in head tag and it works no more: https://jsfiddle.net/me2b0r56/1/

Answer (score 0):

If that's your code (and you want to make all hidden on page load), you have to wait the document to be ready before calling the function:

```
function easySlider(titleP,subTitleP,overlayP){
    var title = titleP;
    var subTitle = subTitleP;
    var overlay = overlayP;

    if(title===true) {
        $(".sliderTitle").css("display","block");
    }else{
        $(".sliderTitle").css("display","none");
    }

    if(subTitle===true) {
        $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display","block");
    }else{
        $(".sliderSubTitle").css("display","none");
    }

    if(overlay===true) {
        $(".sliderOverlay").css("display","block");
    }else{
        $(".sliderOverlay").css("display","none");
    }   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
easySlider(false,false,false);
});
```

Otherwise, if you call the function after the document is loaded, it works fine.